# Is there a way to offer three choices and get a pop up to choose between them?

Tags: input

The only way I think would work would be something like this:

```
inp = input("Choose between A, B and C: ")
if inp = A
    choice = ABCDEFGH
elif inp = B
    choice = IJKLMNO
elif inp =C
    choice = PGQRSTUV
else
    print("Wrong Input")
    break
```

is there any easier way to make a choice between 3 long strings?

Comment: We would need your definition of "easier".  What is not-so-easy about the above solution?  What are your expected results?

Comment: We would also need to know what programming language this is. Python?

Comment: Yeah sorry its phyton

I thought maybe the would be a way to do it with lists like:

list = np.array([ABCDEFGH,IJKLMNO,PGQRSTUV])
ch= choice(list)


and the choice function would be an pop up with these different choices, which i can click on